# Fix markdown formatting of readme file

Tags: markdown, gitlab

I'm trying to include this in a README.md file and it keeps breaking the rendering.

````
```
\{{ variable }}
```
````

Looks like the backslash is breaking the rendering. How can I fix this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your markdown. The problem is in whatever program or application you're using to "render" the markdown. Can't help with that unless you tell us what it is.

Comment: I just tested this on my gitlab installation and it rendered properly. I got a nice code block containing `\{{ variable }}`. can you provide more detail on how it is breaking the rendering? maybe the problem lies somewhere else.